# Zen Coding on Eclipse - Settings file

Tags: eclipse, emmet

Just installed it. Where is the settings file to edit snippets and abbreviations in Eclipse? Like in Notepad++ *'Zen Coding.js'*?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `<Your Eclipse installation folder>/plugins/ru.zencoding.eclipse_0.8.0.201201232221.jar` `ru/zencoding/zencoding.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually edit `zen_settings` in Eclipse plugin (https://github.com/sergeche/eclipse-zencoding), just open Preferences > Zen Coding